# How to perform action globally when record get updated in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Is that possible to run this job `UpdateRateZone` globally wheneven `Consignment` Model gets updated anywhere in the system?

One method is to use `Observer` but observer doesn't work when update multiple reccord at once like

```
Consignment::where('status',1)->update(['address'=>'This']);
```

Is there anything else we can do?

Answer (score 1):

As per laravel docs :

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saving, saved, updating,
> and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models.
> This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a
> mass update.

Laravel does not fire `updated` event in case of mass update, so its not possible as per my knowledge. Other way is to do manually.

Other than `observers` there is methods such [using closures for events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) and [Registering events manually](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#wildcard-event-listeners) but all these methods would work if only `laravel` trigger an event on `mass updation` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a Event Listener for your model. You can read up on more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events)

In short first you need to create an Event for the needed model, so if its a Updated event create something like this.

```
php artisan make:event Consignment/Updated
```

In that file add

```
class Updated
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

 /**
 * @var Consignment
 */
public $consignment;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Consignment $consignment)
{
    $this->consignment= $consignment;
}

/**
 * Get the event consignment property
 *
 * @return Consignment
 */
public function getConsignment()
{
    return $this->consignment;
}
}
```

Now you must create a Listener for this event

```
php artisan make:listener Consignment/UpdatedEvent
```

And in the handle function add youre logic

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  Updated  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(Updated $event)
{
    //
}
```

And all that is left after that is to register the events for you Model and you do that in your Consignment.php class where you add

```
/**
 * The event map for the category.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'updated' => Updated::class,
];
```

Comment: it will work on this query as well? `Consignment::where('status',1)->update(['address'=>'This']);`

Comment: It should work for your query.

Comment: Those are the same events the Observer listens to, but I don't think the events are triggered when updating like that

Comment: Try code before post it. Observers WILL NOT work with mass update or with raw queries

Answer (score -1):

When you do this:

`Model::where('status',1)->update([some stuff]);`

Query Builder's update() method is executed instead of Eloquent's update() method.

If you want to trigger Eloquent events, you need to update rows one by one.
You can fire these events manually, but it's tricky and it's a bad idea.

You could just run the `UpdateRateZone` job manually for all the Consignments that were updated